# Mapping the 'count' on child list property in AutoMapper

Tags: list, automapper

I am working in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application, and have something similar to this for my domain.

```
public class Party
{
    public Cake PartyCake { get; set; }
    public List<Candles> CakeCandles { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map that to the `PartyVM` which looks like so:

```
public class PartyVM
{
    public string PartyCakeName { get; set; }
    public int CandlesCount { get; set; }
}
```

How can I tell AutoMapper to work out the Count of the list when doing its mappings? I have this, but all this does is tell it to ignore!

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Party, PartyVM>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CandlesCount, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Thanks.

Comment: In CandlesCount you want to have number of Candles?Did you tried .ForMember(dest => dest.CandlesCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(c=>c.CakeCandles.Count()));?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AutoMapper supports Count out of the box, your destination member is just named incorrectly. If you name your PartyVM property "CakeCandlesCount" it will have the right value.