# How map depending list to counting property with Automapper

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I Have this Entity:

```
public class Skill : Base
{
    public Skill() { }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<UserSkill> UserSkills { get; set; }
}
```

And this DTO:

```
public class SkillDto
{
    public SkillDto() { }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int AssignedUsers { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

This is my Automapper configuration:

```
configuration.CreateMap<Skill, SkillDto>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
.ForMember(dest => dest.AssignedUsers, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.UserSkills.Count));
```

The last line, tries to count List<> to int property

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.AssignedUsers, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.UserSkills.Count));
```

But, always catch this exception:

> Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below. Add a
>   custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify
>   the source/destination type For no matching constructor, add a no-arg
>   ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
>   ================================================================= Skill -> SkillDto (Destination member list)
>   Uranus.Domain.Entities.Skill -> Uranus.WebAPI.Models.Skill.SkillDto
>   (Destination member list)
>
> Unmapped properties: AssignedUsers

What's wrong?

Comment: I found this answer on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400687/mapping-the-count-on-child-list-property-in-automapper and it works for me. But, Do I need change the name of my counting property? really?

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.