# How can I return a count of child entities?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datatables

So, I have a datatable of `Tickets` in the view:

[image: Tickets View]

Populated by this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tickets").DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: "/api/tickets",
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data: "Id"
            },
            {
                data: "StreetName"
            },
            {
                data: ""
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

The `GetTickets()` API call is this:

```
public IEnumerable<TicketDto> GetTickets()
{
    return _context.Tickets
        .ToList()
        .Select(Mapper.Map<Ticket, TicketDto>);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to populate the Total column of the table as well. To do this, I'll need to select a COUNT of the records in another table, `OwnedTickets` that have the Ticket's `Id` as the OwnedTicket's `TicketId` property.

(Ticket and OwnedTicket are related as `TicketId` from `Tickets` is a foreign key in the table `OwnedTickets`).

Here's a diagram to illustrate their relationship:

[image: ERD]

So, I'd like to be able to store the total number of `OwnedTickets` for each `Ticket` in the "Total" column.

Comment: What language do you need the answer?

Comment: I'm using C# (ASP) for the API controller class and Javascript for the rendering of the datatable. Looking for a solution in either of those if possible.

Comment: So you want a count of OwnedTickets in TicketDto? Automapper can do that: `.ForMember(dest => dest.OwnedTicketCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(t=>t.OwnedTickets.Count()));` or better yet, just [name the destination property properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400687/mapping-the-count-on-child-list-property-in-automapper).